# how to combine two classes that share the same base class in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I give the following example to illustrate my question:

```
class Base
{
 public:
   virtual void do()=0;
}

class A: public Base
{
public:
  void do();
};

class B: public Base
{
 public:
  void do();
}

class AB: public Base
{ 
 public:
 void do()
  {
     a_.do();
     // if not succeed
     {
        b_.do();
     }
    }
private:
 A a_;
 B b_;

}
```

From the above codes, we can see that class `A, B` and `AB` come from the same Base class. class `AB`, however, needs to invoke both class `A` and class `B`. Here is my question: what's the potential problem with the class `AB`? Are there other alternatives?

One alternative might be:

```
class Base
{
 public:
   virtual void do()=0;
}

class A: public Base
{
public:
  void do();
};

class B: public Base
{
 public:
  void do();
}

class AB: public A
{ 
 public:
 void do()
  {
     A::do();
     // if not succeed
     {
        b_.do();
     }
    }
private:

 B b_;

}
```

Comment: You've shown _what_ you want to do, but not _why_ so it's not clear what problem you're trying to solve, so it's hard to say what the valid alternatives are. Knowing what "do()" does would help, because it would tell us whether `AB` is substitutable (in Liskov terms) for either `A` or `B` and so whether deriving from one or them would make sense. (N.B. `do` is a keyword so not a valid function name, and `this.do()` is not valid C++, it should be `this->A::do();`).

Comment: You can do multiple inheritance but it usually is a BAD practice and reveals a problem of conception. You are doing it right.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant: no, MI is not evil in C++. Suggested reading: Bjarne Stroustroup's FAQ entry on this.

Comment: @lorro: It usually force you to violate SRP (Single Responsibility Principle). In its case it won't because the inherited class are inheriting the same one, it's a specific case.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant: .. and in a lot of other cases, it's not, so it's not a rule. IMHO single inheritance is much more abused (instead of composition) than MI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what you really want to achieve. But if all of your classes should only have one copy of instance data from Base, you need a virtual Base class.

The problem from your first example with AB is, that you have three! times data of class Base. One from inherit Base, one as part of Member B which itself derives from Base and the same from Member A. Is that what you intend?

I give you the following snipped to see how you can work with exact ONE copy of Base in all of your class instances. Maybe that is what you want to get?

I add some data to Base to see how construction works while using virtual base classes. It is important that the base class constructor will not be called from the constructors of directly inherited classes! You need to call the constructor directly from the outermost constructor as shown in class AB constructor!

As a remark: Virtual Base classes should be used only if nothing else fits the design. Often the need of such a solutions shows a design problem. But as always in programming: If this fits exactly your needs, it is technically absolutely ok to do it.

```
class Base
{   
    private:
        std::string text;

    public:
        Base( const std::string& str ): text(str) {}
        virtual void Do() { std::cout << text << std::endl; }
};  

class A: virtual public Base
{   
    public:
        A():Base("Default from A") {}
        void FuncA() { std::cout << "FuncA" << std::endl; }
       void Do() { std::cout << "Via A" << std::endl; Base::Do();}
};  

class B: virtual public Base
{   
    public:
        B(): Base ("Default from B") {}
        void FuncB() { std::cout << "FuncB" << std::endl; }
};  

class AB: public A,B 
{   
    public:
        //Important to know that init of Base MUST be done from here and not from A nor B !!
        AB( const std::string &s): Base(s) {}
        void Do() { std::cout << "Via AB" << std::endl; Base::Do(); A::Do(); B::Do();}
};  

int main()
{   
    A a;
    a.Do();
    std::cout << "####" << std::endl;

    B b;
    b.Do();
    std::cout << "####" << std::endl;

    AB ab("Hallo"); 
    ab.Do();
    std::cout << "####" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: OP has no data in `Base` BTW.

Comment: @Jarod42 And we did not know what he want to achieve. So I added data to give a hint for construction and construction order in hope it will help. He accepted the answer, so I believe my idea what not so bad :-)

Answer (score 3):

> what's the potential problem with the class AB?

I don't know of any well known problem that would necessarily arise from your design. You should ask yourself "Why would there be a problem?".

> Are there other alternatives?

There are many alternatives. For example, neither `A` nor `B` contain any state, so you could just as well stop using classes in favor of free functions and replace dynamic binding with a function pointer.

To be able to compare different alternatives, you should first decide what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score -1):

You should inherit from A and B and not from Base, because A and B already do so.

Comment: Since Base is not a virtual base that would mean there are two Base classes, and conversion to the base would be ambiguous. It might be an acceptable solution, but definitely has downsides. (I'm not the downvoter though).